# Unable to integrate Lyft API into Android App

Tags: android, lyft-api

I am trying to integrate the Lyft Ride Request API into my Android app - specifically the Lyft Button.  When I attempt to add my app in their developer's console, I see the following after adding the app:

> On April 15th, Lyft made changes to its developer platform. As a
> result, this application no longer has access to the API platform. You
> can read more about the changes here. If you think this change is made
> in error, please reach out to your Lyft representative.

The link that is provided does not contain any relevant information nor is there anyone or anything to consult on their website for assistance.

Is the Lyft Button no longer available.  If it is, what are the app requirements?

Comment: I find it very frustrating for a company of such a big magnitude like Lyft or Uber to just blankly put something like that in their documentation, without any contact information or how to even contact that team they claim to be "your Lyft representative". Uber has the same wording without saying how to even get in touch with those representatives...[...Uber Business Development representative or Uber point of contact to get access to this API].

Answer (score 1):

So I decided to ignore the No Access message and I went ahead and integrated the Lyft Button API into my application and all seemed to work.

Lyft Button API integration for android is at this URL:
[Lyft Button API](https://developer.lyft.com/docs/android-lyft-button)

One point of confusion was the requirement for a client token and client id.  You do not have to supply a token or an id.  You can use "..." as shown in the API instructions for both values.

I was able to confirm that the button is successful in grabbing start and destination locations and launching the Lyft app which then shows the route and vehicles in the area with ride prices.
There is no sandboxing option for testing, so be careful.  It looks like any rides you order and confirm will be charged to your credit card.